# Google Cloud Storage From Remote Server

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm lost in trying to decipher google's documentation for using cloud storage. All of the documentation that I have been able to find for PHP and Google Cloud seem to be for services running on google cloud. The snippet below uses the **gs://my_bucket/new_file.txt** as an example.

```
$gs_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://my_bucket/new_file.txt');
```

This does not however tell me how to upload images from remote server.

I've looked for PHP libraries and checked composer but can't seem to find what I need. All I want to do is upload a file to the cloud, get the URL of the image and save the url to serve later on. Clean and simple.

I'm currently doing this on S3 and it was all very straight forward and easy to get up and running. For some reason I am missing something here.

Can anyone shed some light, or am I trying to do something google cloud wasn't designed for?

Comment: To start with: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples

Answer (score 1):

When the app runs locally, the gs:// path is mapped to a local GCS emulation layer. You can use [Developer Console](http://console.developers.google.com) or [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to work with the production GCS.